# how can I save files to a system directory from gitlab on merge to master?

Tags: gitlab

We are using gitlab for revision control of rmarkdown files which are used by other parts of our documentation system (they are sourced into other rmarkdown reports).

Is there a way to export all of the *.Rmd files into a system directory (running Linux) when we merge back to the master branch ?

For example, we have a document `tm308-decisionrule.Rmd` in the repository - when we merge from the dev branch to master I want that (and any other Rmd files in the repo) to be saved to `/data/accreditation/decisionrules/` (and to overwrite any previous versions which are in there).

Comment: You could create a CI/CD job, with rules that make it run only on the default/master branch. That job could sync the files using a tool like `rsync`. Would that work?

Comment: Hi @sytech - that sounds promising. I am fine with rsync or some version of scp to copy files from the server to a system NFS for example,  but I don't understand how a CI/CD job could export files in the first place.  What should I be searching for? (or are there tutorials for deploying text or html files) ?  (How do I get the files out of gitlab when a merge occurs).